# Snap 3D cursor to an opaque part of plane (blender)

Tags: python, textures, pivot, transparency, blender

I have a question regarding python scripting in Blender, and I'd really appreciate it if someone could give me at least some conceptual guidelines to how I could do this:

Basically I have around 100 planes (simple primitive planes) and each of them has its own material and each material has it's own transparency map applied to it.

I need a way to snap each of those plane's respective pivots to their opaque parts. I.e. if there is a way to tell the following to blender through python language - "hey, go over every one of these planes, and do the following for each - snap a 3D cursor to an opaque part of the plane (it doesn't matter where exactly, as long as it's inside of an opaque part of the plane) and then snap plane's pivot point to the 3D cursor".

Of course I don't expect anyone to write me a full algorithm for this, I am just asking for a little help and a push in the right direction, as I do have experience with python, but not with blender :/

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find documentation on [blender's python api here](http://www.blender.org/documentation/250PythonDoc/).

Within blender's [image class](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/bpy.types.Image.html) you can access the pixel data at `image.pixels` as an array of floats, 4 floats per pixel (RGBA I think). `image.size[0]` is the width in pixels `image.size[1]` for height.

Given `bpy.data.objects['Plane'].bound_box` is an [8][3] array of points defining the outer extremes of the plane, you can locate a point on the plane for the pixel location to get the target point for the origin. You will also find `bpy.data.objects['Plane'].matrix_world` useful to translate the object coordinates to global.

`bpy.context.scene.cursor_location = Vector((x,y,z))` will move the cursor to where you want.

`bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CURSOR')` will set the active objects origin to the cursor. Note that this works on the active object, so you will need to alter your selection as you go.

Comment: First of all, thank you a lot for your help sambler and I apologize for the delayed reply!

I found what you wrote here very helpful, and I feel like I'm definitely on the right path thanks to you. However the main problem right now is that I don't know how blender treats pixels as units within 3D space, and how would I go about converting a position of a pixel within uv space to it's exact position in 3D space :/...

Comment: After a bit of playing I managed to do it! :) Thank you so much man! What you provided me with is exactly what I needed! I just had to play a bit further with some basic 3D math stuff and experiment a lot with printing :)

Blender seems very easy already!

Thank you very much again man! :)